# JAVA, How to restart my program from the start?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am doing some exercises, I created an if statement and else if so that when the user clicks 2 it will start the program from the start.

The problem is at the else if (yesNo == 2), I don't know what kind of code should I write there to start the program from the start. Can anybody help me? thank you.

```
    if (option == 1) {
        System.out.println("1: DAF");
        System.out.println("2: Mercedes-benz");
        model = in.nextInt();

        if (model == 1) {
            System.out.println("Model: " + mixer2.getModel());
            System.out.println("Age: " + mixer2.getAge());
            System.out.println("Cost: " + mixer2.getCost());
            System.out.println("Capacity: " + mixer2.getCapacity() + "  squares meters");

            System.out.println("For how long do you want the vehicle to hire?, maximum is 12 months and every month cost 4000");
            hireVehicle = in.nextInt();
            cost = 4000 * hireVehicle;
            System.out.println("The total cost is " + cost + " Do you want to proceed?");
            System.out.println("1: yes");
            System.out.println("2: no");
            yesNo = in.nextInt();


            if (yesNo == 1) {
                System.out.println("Now, please enter your first name to complete the contract");
                String name = in.next();
                System.out.println("CUSTOMER CONTRACT");
                System.out.println("Customer name: " + name);
                System.out.println("Duration: " + hireVehicle + " months");
                System.out.println("Date: " + date.date1());
            }
            else if (yesNo == 2){

            }
```

Comment: Wrap your program in loop. You can use something like `do{many; things; }while(condition);`

Comment: do while is your friend. Now search how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a loop like this one :

```
boolean repeat = True;
while (repeat)
{
    if (yesNo ==1)
        repeat = False;
    else if (yesNo == 2)
        repeat = True;
}
```

It might be easier with a do while loop, but i heard they're dirty